# Accord.Net version 3.8.0 Framework download and installation

Tags: c#, .net, accord.net

i m trying to download the accord.net version 3.8.0 from the website

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord.MachineLearning.GPL/

but they say to run the command.
my question is how to run this command.OR download the framework from this site.
2nd problem:
after trying this site i downloaded the framework from other site. the link is given below

https://sourceforge.net/projects/accord-net/?source=typ_redirect

but there is no dll libraries which i add in my project.

my second question is to please tell me how to use this downloaded package. the screenshot of downloaded package is attached[image: downloaded package but don't know how to use it]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Visual Studio, please [follow the Getting Started guide](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Getting-started).

As you can see, you can install the framework without using any commands at all. Just create a new C# project in Visual Studio, then right-click your project, select "Manage NuGet packages", then look for "Accord.NET" in the NuGet packages browser. Install any libraries that you think you would need in the application you are trying to create (i.e. Accord.MachineLearning).

Answer (score 1):

first download the nugGet package manager. the link is given for the download 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManager

after downloading install it. it is the extension for visual studio.
now open a new project and create the application
go to the solution explorer right click the project name. select Nuget packages

a window will appear. select online and in settings check the url of nuget file.
in search option search for accord.machine or whatever library you want.